# Picasso Library and GridView Images

Tags: android, json, gridview, picasso

I want to build an app that displays images in a gridview by using the picasso library. The images are retrieved by a remote server. Should I make an AsyncTask class or is this class handled by Picasso Library itself? All the picasso tutorials I have seen so far seem a bit vague.

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: Yes picasso a powerful image downloading and caching library for Android. You do not need to write the async task for download the image, they handle by this library. let me know if you need more information how to write it i can show you with implement in grid view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it with gridview and if i have any problem I will ask you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its very simple to use picasso lib for loading images in gridview, [as demonstrated here](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso/SampleGridViewAdapter.java),

```
class SampleGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private final Context context;
  private final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

  public SampleGridViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    // Ensure we get a different ordering of images on each run.
    Collections.addAll(urls, Data.URLS);
    Collections.shuffle(urls);

    // Triple up the list.
    ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(urls);
    urls.addAll(copy);
    urls.addAll(copy);
  }

  @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SquaredImageView view = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
    if (view == null) {
      view = new SquaredImageView(context);
      view.setScaleType(CENTER_CROP);
    }

    // Get the image URL for the current position.
    String url = getItem(position);

    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    Picasso.with(context) //
        .load(url) //
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
        .error(R.drawable.error) //
        .fit() //
        .tag(context) //
        .into(view);

    return view;
  }

  @Override public int getCount() {
    return urls.size();
  }

  @Override public String getItem(int position) {
    return urls.get(position);
  }

  @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. Take care.