# get Image from web URL in GridView which is in ScrollView updated weired

Tags: android, gridview

first, i'm live in korea. i just start to write english. so may be not good understand.

when i get Image from server, set Items Name. ex > 1,2,3,4, .. 20

some item could have Image URL or not.

i regist image in server two or more. App's GridView set 6 column and 4 row.

so situation is this.

1(regist Image) 2(regist Image) 3(registImgae) 4 5 6

7(weired part it update 1 Image ) 8 9 10 11 12

13 14 15 16 17 18

19 20

when i get android project, coded like this .

```
 XXXfragment extends customFragment {

 GridView gridView;
 GridAdapter adapter;
 ArrayList<GridItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

 @Override 
 public void onCreate(){
         // someInitialize Coded 
         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<GridItem>(this,items);
         gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(){
      getImagesList(); // some network process
 }


 @Override 
 public void responseData(){
        super();
        items.clear();
        items.addAll( getImageURLItems() );
        setGridViewHeight( gridView );   // set gridView because it inside in ScrollView

        adapter.notifydatasetchanged();// here is problem occured
  }

 public void setGridViewHeight(GridView gridView){
 gridView.post(new Runnable(){
             // initialize items for gridView 
  });

 }
}

    public class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridItem>{

    @Override
    public void getView(
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        ViewHolder listImageHolder;

        AQuery aq = new AQuery( getContext() );
        final GridItem item = getItem( position );
        View v = convertView;
        if ( v == null || v.getId() == R.id.loPhotoAdd  ) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from( getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.grid_item_photo_in_ex, null );     }
            listImageHolder = new ViewHolder();

            listImageHolder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById( R.id.img );
            v.setTag(listImageHolder);
        }else {
            listImageHolder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }


        if ( item != null ) {
            TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.text );
            text.setText( item.title );

            if(item.filePath != null) {
                final int HashCode = listImageHolder.imageView.hashCode();
                Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"position"+position);
                Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"hashcode"+HashCode);


                BitmapAjaxCallback callback = new BitmapAjaxCallback();
                 callback.rotate(true);
                    aq.id(listImageHolder.imageView).image(item.filePath,true,true,200,1,callback).clicked(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                    "itemCateCode : "+ item.categoryCode+"\n"+
                                    "filePath : "+ item.filePath+"\n"+
                                    "itemCode : "+ item.itemCode+"\n"+
                                    "idx : "+ item.idx+"\n"+
                                     "title : "+ item.title+"\n"+
                                            "pos : "+position +"\n"+
                                            "hashCode :"+HashCode
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });;
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Follow the link and have a read on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is answered already. Load the images with picasso to the grid view. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426893/picasso-library-and-gridview-images) is the example. Good luck.